# early 2015 macbook pro with 18.04 powering off randomly when not plugged in

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, crash, macbook, macbook-pro

Good day, the issue I"m having is that when my early 2015 macbook pro with Ubuntu 18.04 installed on it is unplugged, even when the batter is >90% full, it randomly and suddenly will power off. It varies when it does it, from watching a YouTube video to ediding a document. I have tried [resetting the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and removing TLP but to no avail.

While I feel like I've provided good information, please let me know if there is any other information that would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to mention, during testing, it was plugged into an external drive with MacOS on it, it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue after installing virtual box and installing ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04 (can't recall) which never ran as expected on the laptop. After doing this immediately the laptop now seems to shut down like clock work after 1-2 minutes of inactivity, I have not edited High Sierra system files but I am very much so considering it. I do not want to lose the configuration I have done on the macbook however a possible solution would be to back up important files and then factory reset the macbook and reinstall/transfer the backed up files and programs.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Comment: Would having Ubuntu on the machine instead of just a virtual machine make a difference?

Comment: Hey i actually know that in 

System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Click Lock -> Advanced

has a feature to turn off the mac.


Maybe checking your kernels thats start at runtime, if you find a kernel not native to mac you could delete it too.

Virtual Machines run a different architecture in system memory so as far as I know ubuntu can't be installed over iOS since ios is written into the main memory.